# issues with installing mesosphere mesos in ubuntu

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

While installing mesosphere mesos i have faced several issues Ubuntu Linux 
distribution. I have used

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E56151BF
DISTRO=$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
CODENAME=$(lsb_release -cs)
echo "deb http://repos.mesosphere.io/${DISTRO} ${CODENAME} main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list
```

to install mesosphere with

```
sudo apt-get install mesosphere
```

Now as expected mesossphere should download all dependencies like mesos,marathon and zookeeper with it. After i have installed them successfully i wanted to run the mesos as a service with

```
sudo service mesos-master start
```

but system says its unrecognized service. As a solution i had to download mesos separately and start them manually after building the same source code. 
what i am looking for is if there exist any other simple solution to install apache mesos.

Answer (score 0):

you need use

```
sudo apt-get -y install mesos
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install mesosphere
```

to install mesos.

Comment: mesosphere also does the same along with downloading other dependent or additional software like marathon, zookeeper etc